# how to search exact word in table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this search table with multiple words and display multiple results. But I have a problem in search exact word like "Male" and "Female" when I search "Male" the female is also displayed because the female has "male" word. How will I find the exact word?

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
RegExp.escape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
};
}
jQuery(function ($) {
///search this table
$(' #search ').click(function () {
    var searchthis = new RegExp($(' #emp_search ').val().replace(/ /g,"|"), 'i');
    alert(searchthis);
    $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
      //  var text = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase().trim();
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        $(this).toggle(searchthis.test(text));
    });
    });
});
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/wind_chime18/ANLgD/11/**](http://jsfiddle.net/wind_chime18/ANLgD/11/)

Comment: Not sure if in Javascript regex but try the word boundary \b operator "\bmale\b" will probably do the trick

Comment: @vogomatix try my jsfiddle sir.

Comment: Regrettable don't have the time to look, but http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml suggests that word boundaries are implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just added a space:

```
var searchthis = new RegExp(' '+$(' #emp_search ').val().replace(/ /g,"|"), 'i');
```

and updated your fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ANLgD/12/

Comment: what the heck men. you great!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ANLgD/17/

```
 $(function () {
  $(' #search ').click(function () {

    var str = $('#emp_search').val();
    var strary = str.split(' ');

    $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());

        for (var i = 0; i < strary.length; i++) {
            var regex = new RegExp(".*\\b" + strary[i] + "\\b\.*", "gi");
            $(this).toggle(regex.test(text));
            if (regex.test(text)) break;
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: well now it's working but it is not a multiple search anymore. try typing the male female. it will not display anything anymore.

Comment: you guys are so incredible. where did learn all of this. i envy you.

Comment: @Vincent, Its all Practice..Practice..Practice.. The more you code, the more issues will pop up and the more solutions you will find ;)